# Background fixed / cover does not work in Android native browser?

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to have a header with fixed / cover background, but I don't know why the image is not fit to the header although it has a height!
also the image is not shown in android native browser..
I've made a fiddle you can see it in PC and android!

```
The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6Wv6c/2/
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451933/background-sizecover-not-working-in-android-native-browser)

Maybe native browser has problem with shorthand background property. The follow has worked for me.

Try to use explicit css syntax, so replace:

```
background: url('<url>') no-repeat fixed left center / cover
```

with:

```
background-image: url(<url>);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: exactly, I found the answer in another question of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451933/background-sizecover-not-working-in-android-native-browser/20455585#20455585  I remember I deleted this question ! :D