# background-size:cover not working in android native browser

Tags: android, css, background

I'm trying to fit a background image to it's container using `background-size:cover`.
here is my fiddle : [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wv6c/3/)

it works in all browsers but not working in Android native browser..
anybody has any solution please ? thanks

Comment: maybe cuz you need to set witdh without % but in px, thats pure guess, cuz if I remmeber correct android has problem with widths on screen to set.

Comment: you mean I should use px instead of % for all elements ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching about this problem and finding no solution, I deleted background-image from CSS file styles and used an inline style in HTML codes. The problem with android native browser is solved.

I updated the fiddle and it's working in android native browser.

[The Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wv6c/4/)

it seems that android also has problem with parsing background format like this :

```
background: url('...') fixed center center / cover;
```

and we should separate the background-image form others and use it inline, and then use each option separately in css file, like this :

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: @R.Bosma has helpfully added a suggestion (albeit on an answer likely to be removed, as its content is better fit for a comment): "Do not use background-attachment: fixed. Otherwise no scaling will be applied either on Android devices. Local and scroll seem to work fine."

Comment: It worked for when using `html, body {...}` instead of `body {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the background-size property isn't fully supported by older versions of Android's native browser and Chrome for Android. I went through the pain of discovering this the hard way. Instead of using "cover" as a value, do the following:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

What this does is give you the same horizontal feel as "cover" and then automatically sets the height of the image, assuming that the image has intrinsic dimensions.

For further reading, I recommend diving into the [detailed writeup from Sara Soueidan](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-size/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with background-size: cover, the image was fit to the width of the device and below there was white background, and it was fixed when I set background-color using this css:

```
background-color: #fff;
```

or shorthand:

```
background: #fff url('http://cdn.stupiddope.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/IMGP3540.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
```

it doesn't matter which color you pick because it will be invisible.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wv6c/63/)