# Background image not showing on Android Native Browser

Tags: android, css, background

I have a site I am working on http://www.jdwebmanagement.com/draft/18twenty/ and it displays fine on desktop and Chrome browser on Android. However on the native internet browser on Android the background does not show.

I have read other threads about the same kind of issue and tried the solutions but none of them seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this solution work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451933/background-sizecover-not-working-in-android-native-browser

Comment: Hi Manan, no I have separated out all of the in line styles and still doesn't show.